# Find the limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n$

$S_n$ = $\frac{\sin(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$

I need to explain why |$S_n$ - $0$| $\leq$ $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.

There is a theorem that states $a_n \rightarrow a$ and $b_n \rightarrow b$ $( b \neq 0)$, then $\frac{a_n}{b_n} \rightarrow \frac{a}{b}$

I just want to sufficiently for a proof.

Comment: Hint:  $|sin(n)| \leq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. You have
$$
|\sin (n)|\leq 1,\quad n \in \mathbb{R},
$$ giving
$$
|S_n|=\frac{|\sin (n)|}{\sqrt{n}}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

Comment: should i say  since sin<1, is that squeeze thm? or is that normally assumable?

Comment: Yes, this is the squeeze theorem, it is $|\sin n |\leq1$, don't forget the absolute value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use that theorem, because
$\sqrt{n}$ diverges to infinity.

But as other have said, all you need is $|\sin(n)|<1$.